# openid-client wso2 401 Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I try to use node-openid-client to get access code from wso2 identity server.
How can i send authentication credentials?

```
'use strict';

const { Issuer } = require('openid-client');
Issuer.discover('https://localhost:9443/oauth2/oidcdiscovery') // => Promise
  .then(function (wso2Issuer) {
    console.log('Discovered wso2Issuer %s', wso2Issuer);
  });
```

My result:

```
node:23516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AggregateError:
    OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: What is the Identity server version you are using ?

Comment: Is the 5.7.0  version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this `Issuer.discover` method is trying to access a `/.well-known` endpoint. 
The reason for you getting `401 Unauthorized` is because in WSO2 IS 5.7.0 this endpoint is secured by default.

There are two solutions to your problem

1. Send the Authorization: Basic header with base64 encoded user credentials. i.e.: `Authorization: Basic base64encoded(username:password)`
2. Make the endpoint unsecure.

Since this is a discovery endpoint I would say to go with option 2.

- You can make this endpoint unsecure by doing the following; Open the
  `identity.xml` file inside `<IS-HOME>/repository/conf/identity/` and
  locate the `<ResourceAccessControl>` tag.
- Inside that tag you can find a resource matching `<Resource context="(.*)/.well-known(.*)" secured="true" http-method="all"/>` set secured to `false`.
  i.e.: `<Resource context="(.*)/.well-known(.*)" secured="false" http-method="all"/>`

You will need to restart the server for the configuration change to take effect.